# Stop form from submitting on page load

Tags: php, mysql

How do I stop the form from submitting on page load or refresh? I'm not worried about parameterizing right now. Thanks in advance!

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname']
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']

$sql = ("INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]' , ' $_POST[lastname]')");

mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error is: ".mysql_error());


<form name="add-name" id="add-name" method="post" action="/add-name.php">
<button type="submit">Save</button>

<fieldset>
<label>First Name *</label> 
    <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label>Last Name *</label> 
    <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: See also [Prevent from being submitted twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614197/prevent-form-from-being-submitted-twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname']
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname']

   $sql = ("INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]' , '       $_POST[lastname]')");

   mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error is: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: The first line should be:
`if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I missed that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to stop the query from being executed, then bob's code will work.

If you're also trying to stop the "Would you like to re-submit the form" dialog box, then you'll also want to use headers to redirect back to the page after executing the query.

header("Location: /add-name.php"); // assuming add-name.php is the name of your file