# How to prevent resending data to the data base on reload?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm beginner in php. I designed a web page and it works good but when I ***reload***
 the page that I posted something by submitting in it, it resend these text again to the DB and create same record. now the problem is how can I prevent this resending data in to my DB? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent form from being submitted twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614197/prevent-form-from-being-submitted-twice)

Comment: I don't really see how this is an issue. If users want to resend data let them. Besides, most browsers warn users when they are about to re-post data.

Comment: resending data from users is not m problem. my problem occurs when users reload the page. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a REDIRECT to a page with a message that the data was inserted.
and you can use this header function to do that:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

and also you can redirect to a different query. use this code:

```
header("Location: ?page=successfulsending");
```

Then you don't need if clause to check resending the POST data was sent. Just display the successful sending page if page is equal to successfulsending.

Comment: **header("Location: ?page=successfulsending");** works good. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is submit the form with ajax or use the header function in php to redirect after the writing to the db was done.

Comment: OK thanks. but please help me how can I use header function in php to redirect?

Comment: For example `header('Location: index.php'); exit;` where `index.php` is where you want to send the user. Edit. Remember, you need to have zero output before header redirect, or it wont work. That means no echos and no html.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `POST` method in your form, Try this:

```
if( !empty( $_POST ) )
{
   /*
     success is a boolean value which you would put in $success on form successful submission),  do a redirect
   */
   if( $success )
   {
       header( 'HTTP/1.1 303 See Other' );
       header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?message=success' );
       exit();
   }
}
// if the form submission has succeeded then only show your message
if( isset( $_GET[ 'message' ] ) && $_GET[ 'message' ] == 'success' )
{
?>
  <h2>Thank you</h2>
  <p>
  Your submission is successful.
  </p>    
<?php
}
else
{
?> 
   <!-- submission is not with post method, So show error message and so on ... -->    
<?php
}
```

This would tell:

- If the submission is not a POST request or there is no `?message=success` appended to the url then show an error message to the user.
- If the submission is a POST request, then process the form:

  - if processing succeed, then redirect the user to a new page (by appending the `?message=success` to url you have)
  - if in url you have `?message=success` then show him a thank message.
- If form processing failed, then show him an error message or even show the form again.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: thanks. it looks good. but where should I put Boolean value '**$success=1** ' in code?